# Opening 500+ nodes at once in d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

Currently I am trying to expand a d3.js tree which contains over 100,000 nodes. Many leafs exist under multiple parents, as they fit multiple sections/items/regions. Searches performed by the user results in the tree opening up to all leafs with that node ID. This can result in the graph trying to open up, on rare occasions, up to 2000 leaf nodes at once. Currently, I have found the only way to do this without crashing Chrome is to use the following `setInterval` code.

```
var timeout = setInterval(function(){
    for(var j = i; j < i + 10 ; j++){
        makeEl(d[j]);
        Search.rules += (j+1) + ") " + Graph.findNode(d[j]) + "<br><br>";
        highlightPathTo(d[j].id);
        if(j >= d.length - 1){
            //When all of the elements have been itterated through.
            clearInterval(timeout);
            highlight.selected = d; 
            $('#highlights').removeClass('empty'); 
            break;
        }
    }
    i+=10;
}, 500);
```

However, this takes minutes and is very laggy. I there any other way to accomplish opening this number of nodes in one go that would result in a quicker completion?

Answer (score 1):

Not likely. JavaScript and Browsers can't magically transcend the limits of physics (or your computer). Browsers have come a long way handling huge documents. But there are limits. I don't know for sure how much memory each tree node needs but if each of them needs just 1 KB, we're talking about 100 MB raw data which needs to be rendered on the screen. If each nodes just takes 10 ms to render, simply drawing the page will take 1000 seconds.

So my guess without looking more closely at the problem is that you can't do it. And you probably shouldn't: The human brain isn't able to process that much information nor is there a computer screen which could display it all. Think harder about what you really want to achieve and find a better representation.

You can dump a ton of data on your poor user but that will just drown them. Find a way to present just the important bits, the few gems under the ton of garbage.